# Access objects from context with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

A while ago, using Riverpod, you used to be able to create this from a class:

```
final human=ChangeNotifierProvider((ref)=>Human());
```

with Human being just a simple class with a boolean attribute.

And then access its attributes anywhere in the app (from within a build function) with this:

```
context.read(human).alive=true;
```

but now, with the upgraded SDK and packages, I get this.

> The method 'read' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.

Does anyone know how I can still pull up that object in a similar way, please?

Comment: The point of riverpod instead of provider package is to steer away from context api of flutter, so that you can access riverpod references outside of flutter's build method too.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read your `ChangeNotifierProvider` using the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) syntax.

If you are actually using Riverpod, you need to access your provider using a `ref` object.

You need to either:

- Change your StatelessWidget/StatefulWidget to a ConsumerWidget/ConsumerStatefulWidget:

```dart
class YourWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const YourWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.read(human).alive = true;

    ...
  }
}
```

- Use a `Consumer` widget:

```dart
{
  ...

  child: Consumer(
    builder: (context, ref, child) {
      ref.read(human).alive = true;

      ...
    }
  ),
}
```

Also, need to have a `ProviderScope` in your widget tree. Ideally, on the very top.